# Erro ao compartilhar session do HTTP com socket.io. io.sets "is not valid".

Tags: node.js, express.js, socket.io

Estou aplicando o passo a passo do livro "Node.js, aplicações real-time" do Caio Ribeiro Pereira. Tudo bem até a parte de compartilhar a express-session do HTTP para o socket.io.

Até onde vejo não tem nada errado, mas quando tento ligar o server, aparece isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O server liga e da pra navegar pela aplicação mas cai assim que tento entrar na rota do chat.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o meu código referente ao erro da primeira imagem

```
io.set(function(socket, next) {
    var data = socket.request;
    cookieSec(data, {}, function(err) {
        var sessionID = data.signedCookies[KEY];
        SesMemStore.get(sessionID, function(err, session) {
            if (err || !session) {
                return next(new Error('acesso negado'));
            } else {
                socket.handshake.session = session;
                return next();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Seria algum problema de atualização do express ou do socket.io?

Comment: Quanto ao segundo erro, voce esta tentenado enviar as headers depois do conteudo, o que é impossivel pelo HTTP. Quanto ao socket.io / express informe que versao esta usando para podermos saber.

Comment: ^1.2.1 é a versão do meu socket.io. Quanto ao header atrasado, por que isso está ocorrendo já que é um processo que normalmente não é manipulável?

Comment: @OlimonF. esqueci de te marcar

Answer (score 1):

Creio que essa API do `socket.io` está deprecada. A solução seria mudar seu uso
do método `Server.prototype.set` pelo `Server.prototype.use`, que vai plantar um middleware como aqueles do express.

Há uma versão atualizada dos exemplos do livro do Caio Ribeiro Pereira.
Acho que [esse exemplo](https://github.com/caio-ribeiro-pereira/livro-nodejs/blob/5ccc6ccb83ec83cf3bf8a1382b14c46677c39f07/projeto/ntalk/app.js#L43-L56)
demostra o que você está tentando fazer, usando `Server.prototype.use`:

Encontrei um artigo do `socket.io` explicando as diferenças desde a versão 0.9,
especificamente no que diz respeito a autenticação, sugiro que dê uma olhada [aqui](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#authentication-differences).

O seu código deve funcionar com essa pequena mudança de `set` para `use`:

```js
io.use(function(socket, next) {
  var data = socket.request;
  cookieSec(data, {}, function(err) {
    var sessionID = data.signedCookies[KEY];
    SesMemStore.get(sessionID, function(err, session) {
        if (err || !session) {
            return next(new Error('acesso negado'));
        } else {
            socket.handshake.session = session;
            return next();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Da documentação do `socket.io`, traduzida livremente para o português:

> ## Namespace#use(fn:Function):Namespace
>
> Registra um middleware; uma função que é executada para toda conexão (`Socket`) que chega e recebe como parâmetros o socket e uma função para opcionalmente passar a executar o próximo `middleware` registrado.

Aqui, `Namespace#use(fn:Function):Namespace`, significa que isso é um método sobre a classe `Namespace`, que recebe uma função como argumento e retorna um `Namespace`, para chaining. É o padrão de retornar o `this` para poder encadear métodos (outro exemplo seria o `superagent`: `request.get(url).query(query).end(fn);`).

Isso pode parecer confuso, porque o objeto `io` no seu código é uma instância da classe `Server`, não da classe `Namespace`. A ideia é que você pode criar vários objetos `Namespace`, exatamente como você pode criar vários objetos `Router` no `express` 4, cada um com o seu próprio conjunto de handlers e middlewares.

Por padrão, `Server.prototype.use` vai chamar `Namespace.prototype.use` sobre o `Namespace` padrão, que maneja as conexões à `/`. Isso é similar à relação entre o `Application` e o `Router` do `express`.